# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration... only sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, localhost, koala

I am using the facebook SDK for local rails development, and have changed my site URL and canvas URL set to `localhost:3000/settings` and `localhost:3000/facebook/index` respectively. After a user authenticate at `settings/` they would be redirect to `facebook/index`
However on either pages I get this message

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

This occurs occasionally and not all the times and it causes the facebook SDK (that makes a pop up login) to give the same error message when I tried to log in. I am not really sure what could be causing this, does anyone know why?

EDIT: NVM this is fixed, I found out that fb.js was being loaded twice, bad mistake!